# output redirection in Unix and C

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to run a script inside my C program using `system()` command. Inside `main()`, I run the script and it returns the results. How can I put the result of the script in some string and check for conditions? I know I can do it with files but was wondering if its possible to put the result into a string.

Sample would be like:

```
main()
{
  system("my_script_sh"); // How can I get the result of the my_script_sh
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the system command for that.  The best thing to do is use [popen](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_popen.htm):

```
  FILE *stream;
  char buffer[150];    
  stream = popen("ls", "r");
  while ( fgets(buffer, 150, stream) != NULL ){
      // Copy the buffer to your output string etc.
  }

  pclose(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) and read the stream into a `char *` buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest thing to do would be to take `system("my_script_sh")` out of your program and invoke the program from the shell with a pipe -- e.g.: `my_script_sh | ./your_c_program` and then your C program just reads from stdin (file descriptor 0).

If that is not possible, then have a look at `man 3 popen`. Basically, you use `popen` instead of `system` and it gives you a file handle that you can read from to get the output of the program.

Here are a few links that might be useful:

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html
- http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Programming-with-pipes.html
- http://www.metalshell.com/source_code/23/Popen.html
- http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node12.html